# Spring/Hibernate/TestNG - manual session and transaction setup

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, spring, testng

I am trying to create a testcase for my DAO classes that use plain Hibernate API (no Spring stuff like HibernateTemplate,HibernateDaoSupport), just like this:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(obj);
```

I have the appropriate sessionFactory and transactionManager definition in spring context as shown in the spring docs.

What I want is to open a transaction in my start up code and rollback at the end.

So this is different from the default Spring unit testing supporting concept of transaction for every test method call and so I could not extend AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests.

I need a way to start a transaction and somehow feed it in session factory. I feel this should be extremely easy but could not achieve after lot of reading and experiments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `HibernateTemplate`, you can use `transactionManager` directly as described in [10.6.2 Using the PlatformTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic-ptm).

Comment: Yes, thats what I want to do, but I need to somehow couple this to Hibernate sessions and this is the hard part for me.

Comment: @m17: If you have properly configured `HibernateTransactionManager`, it should be coupled automatically, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  Session session = factory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  ...
  tx.commit();
  session.close();
} catch (SomeException e) {
  tx.rollback();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Actually I could not use this as my DAO uses internally sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). So I need a way to "save back" the session and associated transaction.
In productive environment, I use spring declarative transaction on service layer and everything happens transparently for me. But in test I need to manually handle this "transparency"

Comment: @m17 ah, i see, didn't read your question throughly i guess. In my DAOs i usually create getSession() and setSession() methods so I can use the DAO i IOC. So in my junit tests I create the session, with or without transaction, and set it on the DAO.

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)

annotate the test method using above

Comment: As far as I understand, this will enclose each method in separate transaction. And it will commit this transaction if no exception is thrown ?.